# Semantic UI - How do you display error messages in error block aswel as inline

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

I am using semantic ui and would like to display error messages in my form

the problem is that i have either a choice of displaying them in an error block or using the inline labels.

is there a way that i can display the errors in both at the same time?

so it currently look like

```
$('form').form({
 fields : validationRules,
 inline : true,
 on : 'blur'
});
```

which gives me the errors that appear in the labels, but need the errors to appear inside the error block too

```
<div class="ui error message"></div>
```

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: that's a good question, I honestly prefer to use external validation like ko.validation for knockout and just use semantic for the UI. So far I cannot see an option to make such a config possible. However, try to create a change request on github or even implement it by yourself and pull it. The Semantic team is very responsive and they change stuff very fast :)